# Отфильтровывание списка thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

нужно отредактировать одну статью, но вылазят все, можете подсказать как это сделать
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Главная страница

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Заметки</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row align-items-center p-3 px-md-4 mb-3 bg-white border-bottom shadow-sm">
    <nav class="my-2 my-md-0 mr-md-3">
        <div class="bd-example">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Добавить заметку</button>
            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Новая заметка</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <form action="/" method="post">
                                    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Заголовок" class="form-control"><br>
                                    <textarea name="mtext" placeholder="Введите текст" class="form-control"></textarea><br>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Добавить</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary" href="#">Поиск</a>
</div>
<div class="pricing-header px-3 py-3 pt-md-5 pb-md-4 mx-auto text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Заметки</h1>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="card-deck mb-3 text-center">
            <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm"  th:each="el : ${posts}">
                <h4 class="card-header" th:text="${el.title}"></h4>
                <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4 ">
                    <li class="card-body" th:text="${el.mtext}"></li>
                    <a>
                    <div class="bd-example">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success my-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalo">Редатировать</button>
                        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModaloLabel">Редактировать заметку</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div th:each="el : ${posts}" class="modal-body">

                                        <form action="/" method="post">
                                            <input type="text" th:value="${el.title}" name="title" placeholder="Заголовок" class="form-control"><br>
                                            <textarea name="mtext"  placeholder="Введите текст" class="form-control" th:text="${el.mtext}"/><br>
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Отредактировать</button>
                                        </form>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </a>
                    <a>
                    <div class="bd-example">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger my-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalo1" th:href=" '/' + ${el.id}">Удалить</button>
                        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalo1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalo1Label">Удалить заметку</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <form action="/" method="post">
                                            <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Заголовок" class="form-control"><br>
                                            <textarea name="mtext" placeholder="Введите текст" class="form-control"></textarea><br>
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Удалить</button>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </a>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Основной контроллер

```
package com.IK.notes.Controllers;

import com.IK.notes.Models.Post;
import com.IK.notes.Repo.PostRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class MainController
{
    @Autowired
    private PostRepository postRepository;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String notes(Model model)
    {
        Iterable<Post> posts = postRepository.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("posts",posts);
        return "notes";
    }

    @PostMapping("/")
    public String notePostAdd(@RequestParam String title, @RequestParam String mtext, Model model)
    {
        Post post = new Post(title, mtext);
        postRepository.save(post);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

Comment: Тут много вариантов. Правка заметки на отдельной странице с отдельным маршрутом, Получение формы для редактирования с помощью XMLHttpRequest, последующей отсылкой куда либо. Либо целиком и полностью асинхронное получение данных, построение формы, извлечение данных из формы и отсылка асинхронной формы на клиенте.

Comment: плюс у вас ошибка в логике. если Вы измените значение заметки и отправите форму у существующей заметки, то у вас продублируется заметка(но уже со свежими данными)

Comment: а ещё, если сильно не менять текущий вариант, то можно вывести не одно модальное окно с 4 формами, а 4(и больше) модальных окон, в каждом из которых будет своя форма. и при нажатии на кнопку открывать нужное...но вот новый метод для правки имеющейся заметки (или правка имеющегося, чтобы он мог как создавать та и редактировать)